# Accessing a Linux formatted SD card via Ubuntu VM machine

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I'm a total Linux noob so please be gentle!

I have a Linux formatted SD card inserted into my Win 10 based laptop. I'd like to access this within an ubuntu VM machine that I have on the laptop.

I followed this guide:
https://www.htpcguides.com/how-to-use-sd-card-reader-in-vmplayer-and-vmworkstation/

However though I completed the instructions and it shows within vmplayer virtual machine settings, I'm cue less as to how to access it within ubuntu.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to open the file manager in Ubuntu user inteface by clicking on the "Files" icon somewhere on the desktop and see all your main directories and external devices. Your SD card should be listed in the suggestions

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't show?  I've tried the other locations and it just shows `computer` and `settings`?

Comment: Can you try running this command: `xdg-open /media/*`. This is supposed to open all external drives connected to your pc in different windows

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it returns the following: `xdg-open: unexpected argument ' /media/floppy0'`

Comment: Seems like your external device can not be open by your system. This happens if the system is corrupted or just not compatible with Ubuntu. At this point, you can reformat your SD card or install a diagnose tool to repair it. You can easily find online a bunch of tools for Linux you can install from the command line. An other trick would be to try to open this SD card first in Windows. They have a good recovery tool which can fix corruption problems automatically.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.  The SD card was actually an official SD card for a raspberry pi (comes with NOOBS apparently).  I downloaded Raspbian and re-flashed the drive and hey presto - it appears straight in the `other locations`.
Thanks very much for the help